# How can I mass lock/unlock channels in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Hello stack overflow users,
I am trying to achieve mass-locking/unlocking channels in this coding language. The commands return no error, but it doesn't lock all the channels. I gave the bot permissions and coded this myself, can anyone help?

My code is here:

```
@my_bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
async def Mass_Lock(ctx):
  channels = ctx.guild.channels
  role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="@everyone")
  for channel in channels:
    if channel == discord.TextChannel:
      await channel.set_permissions(role, send_messages=False)

    if channel == discord.VoiceChannel:
      await channel.set_permissions(role, speak=False, video=False, connect=False)

@my_bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
async def Mass_Unlock(ctx):
  channels = ctx.guild.channels
  role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="@everyone")
  for channel in channels:
    if channel == discord.TextChannel:
      await channel.set_permissions(role, send_messages=True)

    if channel == discord.VoiceChannel:
      await channel.set_permissions(role, speak=True, video=True, connect=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is wrong, to check the type of the channel you can use `isinstance()`.

```
if isinstance(channel, discord.TextChannel):
    #
```

or alternatively:

```
if channel.type == discord.ChannelType.text:
    #
```

Also there is no `video` permission in `VoiceChannel` its called `stream`. so it should be like:

```
await channel.set_permissions(role, speak=False, stream=False, connect=False)
```

Comment: uhh it didn't work. It is still the same: not receiving errors, not masslocking/unlocking channels.

Comment: Maybe your bot doesn't have access to all the channels? It works for me. Also, I fixed the alternative way to check the channel type, it was wrong.

Comment: @EricPlayzYT Also, there is no permission for `video` its called `stream` instead. That's probably the issue.

Comment: i gave it administrative privileges, i dont know what the issue is.

Comment: @EricPlayzYT As I said, it's because there is no `video` permission in `VoiceChannel`, use `stream` instead and I believe your issue will be resolved.

Comment: i done that already still didn't work

Comment: @EricPlayzYT I don't know what to tell you, it works perfectly for mine. Could you maybe show me your imports?